# Python one line if condition like in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

This is a valid syntax in JavaScript:

```js
const myVar = true;
myVar && myFunction() // function will be executed
```

The same behavior can be achieved like this in Python:

```py
myVar = True
if myVar: 
  myFUnction()  # function will be executed
```

Is there a Pythonic way how to get the same one-liner like in Javascript ***without*** explicitly using an `if` statement?

Comment: `myVar and myFunction()`? But don't.

Comment: Have you tried moving that all in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`and` is a short-circuit in python (as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)), so

```
myVar and myFunction()
```

will give you what you want

Comment: @Patrik please don't do that in "real" code though, it's hard to read and error-prone.

Comment: I was just curious if something similar is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pythonic way to do this, because oneliners make code reading harder.

However, you could just do `if True: print('a')`